# Putting a constraint on the output of the neural network

Tags: regression, neural-networks, complex-numbers, activation-function

I am using a neural network to input some complex numbers and to obtain complex numbers. I converted the input complex numbers into real values by stacking the real part and imaginary parts as a vector. I used the ReLU function as an activation function. I need to put a constraint of unit modulus in the output value.

I tried to implement the unit modulus constraint by calculating the amplitude of the complex numbers at the output of the activation function and rescaling the output with it. I used the rescaled version of the outputs to calculate the loss for the neural network.

I am not getting satisfactory loss values from the neural network.

I would like to clarify two things.

1. Is it a good practice to modify (in my case rescaling) the output of the activation function before supplying it to the loss function?
2. How can I impose the unit modulus constraint for the output in other ways?

Comment: What loss function are you using?

Comment: If the output needs to have unit modulus, then your output is just the argument right? You can map the angles $[0,2\pi)$ onto the unit interval or the real line.

Comment: My loss function is of the form $$ ||HX-S||^2 $$ where H is a complex matrix with entries drawn from complex standard gaussian distribution, X is the complex matrix with unit modulus entries and S is the matrix with entries randomly drawn from the set e^(pi/4), e^(3*pi/4), e^(5*pi/4) and e^(7*pi/4).

Comment: I converted all the complex expressions into real ones by stacking the real and imaginary parts of the original matrices. I cannot simply get the argument as the output. I need the real and imaginary parts as output.